# Load DOM Fully even for Ajax

Tags: c#, dom

IS there any library that is capable to execute javascript and load all the ajax page and construct the DOM and return the fully constructed DOM to me in C#?

Comment: You may be interested in [WatiN](http://watin.org/)

Comment: Hi I tried Watin, it seems internally it still uses IE webbrowser component (for the IE browser), so I skip Watin and directly uses webbrowser component from System.Windows.Forms namespace. Correctly if i am wrong though

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to host an instance of `WebBrowser` in your application, so the IE Javascript engine will be fine, and the DOM is exposed via the `.Document` proeprty. You can also bind to DOM events as well.

`WebBrowser` is available to WinForms and WPF/Silverlight applications, however if you want to do anything in a headless fashion you're probably going to run into problems. Is this in a server application or a desktop application?

Comment: hi Dai, this is in Web Application, can I know what problems will I have if I am using it in headless fashion?

Comment: It won't work as `WebBrowser` requires a Windows Session and GDI context to operate in.

Comment: Hi Dai, it works! I use WebBrowser control in ASP.NET to load DOM and it works even though there is no UI rendering for it. So Without windows session and gdi, it still works

Comment: That... is surprising. Can you please post your code? I'd like to see it.